# ODBC driver does not support the requested properties in EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im having a problem with this driver issues or something, here is my code, in my previous worksheet its working fine but when i copied the code and transferred it here the error pops out " Run Time Error ODBC driver does not support the requested properties" what seems to be the problem?

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection



Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$] WHERE "
If cmbGroup.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " [Group Name]='" & cmbGroup.Text & "'"
End If

If cmbPolicy.Text <> "" Then
If cmbGroup.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Policy Status]='" & cmbPolicy.Text & "'"
Else
strSQL = strSQL & " [Policy Status]='" & cmbPolicy.Text & "'"
End If
End If

If cmbOfficer.Text <> "" Then
If cmbGroup.Text <> "" Or cmbPolicy.Text <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Case Officer]='" & cmbOfficer.Text & "'"
Else
strSQL = strSQL & " [Case Officer]='" & cmbOfficer.Text & "'"
End If
End If

If cmbGroup.Text <> "" Or cmbPolicy.Text <> "" Or cmbOfficer.Text <> "" Then

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection



OpenDB cnn


rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic 'this code gets the error




Set cnn = Nothing




If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
Sheets("Company View").Visible = True
Sheets("Company View").Select
Range("dataSet").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
With Range("dataSet")
.Select
.Copy
End With
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Else
MsgBox "I was not able to find any matching records.", vbExclamation + 
vbOKOnly
Set rs = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub

End If
```

this one is my ADODB Connection

```
Private Sub OpenDB(ByRef cnn As ADODB.Connection)

cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, 
*.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
cnn.Open

End Sub
```

thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce that error (it works fine). Maybe you are using a very old driver that doesn't support `adOpenKeyset` or `adLockOptimistic`? I do however get an error on `[Data$]` where `$` is not allowed in the name.

Comment: @itsLex Hi thanks for your response, i am currently using MS Office 2013, and ticked the Active X Data Object Control 6.0, I have tested ticking the previous version but still it produces the same problem

Comment: I wasn't refering to ADO (I used 2.8) but to the Microsoft Excel Driver which I think is the ODBC driver (based on the Jet Engine?). It should be from at least 2014 (32-bit version) or 2015 (64-bit version).